# Install elementary OS as a VM in VirtualBox (OSX host)?

Tags: virtualbox

Looking for confirmation if I can install elementary OS.
I've set up an empty VM in VirtualBox 5.0.8 (OSX host)
and will download the files, set up the USB stick.
It should work.  Any warnings or cautions I've missed?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install

elementary OS as **guest** on OS X ( **host**)

In this case, you **no need** to create a live usb or something to install. The only one you need is `.iso` file.

Here are instructions to install:

1. Create Virtual Machine

   Open VBox --> Select **New** --> click on <kbd>Next</kbd> until you create VM.
   (If you want to do any changes to default options, you can change)
2. Now we need to install directly from `.iso` (to avoid creating live usb/cd)

   > If you have only `live usb`, and **no** `.iso` then head straight to **Note** at the bottom)

   First place `.iso` file in a particular location.

   Now close Virtual Machine (not VBox) and

   open **settings** --> **storage**  --> select Adds Optical Drive (green + with disk image)

   ![image: Imgur]

   [image: Imgur]
3. Clicl on  <kbd>Choose disk</kbd>  and navigate to location of `.iso` file.
4. Select `.iso` file and click on  <kbd>Open</kbd>  and then click on <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. Now close settings and **start** Virtual Machine

**Note**:

VirtualBox itself does not support booting from a USB device. But there is a way, for that see [my post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-vbox) in Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to make an USB stick for installing on Virtualbox. Just download the ElementaryOS image and install a new VM in Virtualbox.

To create a new VM in Virtual box click the new button, select linux and Ubuntu in the initial screen. Follow the rest of the steps.

hope this helps

Comment: This answer doesn't quite work for me. I have a number of issues.

First, after the installation process is finished and it asks to Restart Now, the system hangs during the boot-up sequence. I have to forcibly shutdown the virtual machine.

Second, when I successfully boot up into elementary, it's in 640x480 screen resolution. There is no other resolution option in Settings. This resolution is completely unusable.

Comment: Did you try installing the _guest additions_ to your box? You can do so by booting your box and go to the vbox menu and select _devices -> install guest additions cd image..._ and install the _guest additions_.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I get an error message: "Unable to insert the virtual optical disk /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine. Would you like to try to force insertion of this disk?" I click on Force Unmount and nothing happens.